# How to delete all keys from all elements of a JSON string containing specific value in a Python function

Tags: python

How to remove all the Keys under all elements that have a value 'NONE', so in this example busCode, effectivedate and col1. Sample Json and the python code that I tried are pasted here

```
  {
  "colo": {
  "TrBus":{
   "trade": "Test999", 
   "busCode": "NONE",
   "Trtype": "XXX",
   "sortOrder": "78654",
   "effectivedate": "NONE",
   "expirationdate": "31-DEC-9999"
  } 
  "TrCol":{
    "Col1": "NONE",
    "Col2": "Conf"
   }     }
  }
```

I started off with this but doesn't work as expected

```
 def constructJson(jsonstr):
 jdata = json.load(jsonstr)
 for key, value in jsonstr:
   if value == 'NULL':
     del key
 return jdada
```

Comment: 1. `for key, value in jsonstr:` should be `for key, value in jdata:` 2. `del key` should be  `del jdata[key]` and 3. this is not recursive (meaning, it doesn't handle nested values)

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20558699/python-how-recursively-remove-none-values-from-a-nested-data-structure-lists-a) is very similar to yours. You can just replace `is not None` with `!= "NONE"` in the accepted answer and then `return remove_none(jdata)` will work.

Comment: This solution worked. Thanks Boris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution creates a recursive function to iterate over the dict and remove the 'NONE's:

```
def del_none(obj):
    for key, value in obj.copy().items():
        if isinstance(obj[key], dict):
            obj[key] = del_none(obj[key])
        else:
            if value == 'NONE':
                del obj[key]
    return obj
```

Defining the original dictionary as:

```
original_dict = { "colo": {
  "TrBus":{
   "trade": "Test999", 
   "busCode": "NONE",
   "Trtype": "XXX",
   "sortOrder": "78654",
   "effectivedate": "NONE",
   "expirationdate": "31-DEC-9999"
  }, 
  "TrCol":{
    "Col1": "NONE",
    "Col2": "Conf"
   }
  } 
  }
```

And calling the function:

```
new_dict = del_none(original_dict)
```

It produces the following output:

```
new_dict
{'colo': {'TrBus': {'Trtype': 'XXX',
   'expirationdate': '31-DEC-9999',
   'sortOrder': '78654',
   'trade': 'Test999'},
  'TrCol': {'Col2': 'Conf'}}}
```

Comment: Your function doesn't return a new dict - it modifies the original in-place.

Comment: Indeed, I wasn't updating the element on the recursive call. Thanks for pointing this out, @ekhumoro.

Comment: Thank you Daniel, this solution also worked.

Comment: Is there a way to update a 'testvalue'  anywhere in the nested JSON structure to a 'newvalue'  without knowing the Key PATH?

Comment: You can add this following code in the else condition: if value == 'testvalue': obj[key] = 'newvalue'

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
def constructJson(jsonstr):
  jsondata = json.load(jsonstr)
  for key, value in jsondata:
    if value == 'NULL':
      del jsondata[key]
  return jsondata
```